# How to redirect after File upload?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a File.aspx form where I display all the files.

When I upload a file I am using a upload.aspx file to run c# code to upload the file.

The thing is that at the end , I want to refresh the page automatically to display the new file upload but apparently it's not redirecting even if all the parameters are good.

This is the code I use

```
        HttpContext postedContext = HttpContext.Current;
        string param = Request.UrlReferrer.Query;
        string param2 = Request.UrlReferrer.Query;
        var url = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(param).Get("projectName");
        var url2 = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(param2).Get("projectId");
        HttpPostedFile file = postedContext.Request.Files[0];
        string name = file.FileName;
        byte[] binaryWriteArray = new
        byte[file.InputStream.Length];
        file.InputStream.Read(binaryWriteArray, 0,
        (int)file.InputStream.Length);
        //FileStream objfilestream = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~\\" + "\\Files\\" + url + "\\" + name), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        FileStream objfilestream = new FileStream(("C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\Clientportal\\Files\\" + url + "\\" + name), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        objfilestream.Write(binaryWriteArray, 0, binaryWriteArray.Length);

        objfilestream.Close();
        string[][] JaggedArray = new string[1][];
        JaggedArray[0] = new string[] { "File was uploaded successfully" };
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string strJSON = js.Serialize(JaggedArray);
        Response.Write(strJSON);

        Response.Redirect(string.Format("Files.aspx?projectId={0}&projectName={1}", url2, url));
```

Any ideas ? I'm a bit stuck because I use this response.redirect everywhere and it works only when the code is in the same code file...

Maybe it's because of the fact that I try to redirect from another code file ?

Comment: Does ASP.NET allow you to output anything before a redirect ? a Redirection is simply a location header being sent in the header to the client. But it's ONLY the HEADER anything before that and the page gets content. Or that's how I'm used to it. So try commenting out the Response.write and check again?

Comment: Doesnt work . It is strange because when I use this redirection it works fine when it's inside the same code file . But here i'm calling another one and it doesn't want to redirect. I did remove the Response of the Json and it still doesnt change anything .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would attempt to do reload on client side by using javascript:

```
window.location.reload()
```

if the JSON you get as a response contains message "File was uploaded successfully"
If you are not using ajax for submitting the file you don't need to write json. It's enough to redirect to the suitable url that contains a parameter that identifies status of file upload operation.

Comment: Window.location.reaload() is not allowed

Comment: Think your right. From the info I think the OP wants some sort of success page that redirects to the file or page to view the file. So client side redirect would be the way. But can't you use window.location = "example.com"; ?

Comment: You can try commenting out Response.Write(strJSON); 
Your code will start working.

Comment: @JohannduToit Of course you can. By setting window.location with corresponding url you'll redirected to right page.

Comment: Yes just never saw the reload() method before.

Comment: Doesnt work .
It is strange because when I use this redirection it works fine when it's inside the same code file . But here i'm calling another one and it doesn't want to redirect. 
I did remove the Response of the Json and it still doesnt change anything .

Comment: Unfortunately I've no experience with asp.net at all so I'm not able to help. You could try to attach with debugger and see if line is executing or some exception are thrown.